# Phone otp and Verification without Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, dart-pub

i have Google sign-in in the Logins screen, and i have another page to verify the user phone number.

I have use firebase Phone auth to verify phone number but it change the FirebaseAuth.currentUser from google uid to phone authentication uid, which is not what i want.

so i found a package [flutter_otp](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_otp) but this plugin is not working fine.

so i want to send SMS otp and verify it without firebase.

Thanks